# XmlSerializer trying to load unrelated dll in .NET

Tags: .net, dll, xml-serialization, 32bit-64bit, odp.net

I have a class which is using classes from Oracle.DataAccess.dll (32-bit) in its methods. These methods are called on server (32-bit). None of class' properties are of type belonging to Oracle.DataAccess.dll

In client we have referred the same dll and the following code runs fine in 32-bit machine, but not in 64-bit machine.

```
    Type t = typeof(ClassA);
    XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(t);
```

On 64-bit machines getting following error:

```
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.111.7.20, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
File name: 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.111.7.20, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializerContract.CanSerialize(Type type)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.LoadGeneratedAssembly(Type type, String defaultNamespace, XmlSerializerImplementation& contract)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String defaultNamespace)
```

Why is CLR trying to load Oracle.DataAccess.dll despite the class not having any property belonging to the dll ?

**EDIT**
The exception is not occurring when we pass an empty XmlAttributeOverrides

```
XmlAttributeOverrides o = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(t, o);
```

Comment: When you pass in `XmlAttributeOverrides` the XML serializer always creates a new temporary assembly from scratch and does not check for cached or pre-generated serializer assemblies. Do you pre-generate these?

Comment: No we don't pre-generate

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter whether you do. new XmlSerializer(t) and new XmlSerializer(t, o) take slightly different code paths, and in the latter case the method that throws the exception you quote is never called. I have doubts whether the resulting serializer will work, though.

Comment: In the two constructors of XmlSerializer, the difference is the XmlAttributeOverrides parameter and it is empty, so it shouldn't make any difference in the resulting output/xml?

Comment: It shouldn't. I meant that the offending assembly might get loaded (and throw and exception) when you try to use the serializer. After all, there is a reason `new XmlSerializer(t)` throws that exception, even if my psychic debugging powers are too weak to tell you why. Also, a minor point to keep in mind, you are compiling a new temporary assembly every time you call the overload taking `XmlAttributeOverrides`.

Answer (score 1):

This error usually means that the assembly is a mixed assembly, i.e. it contains both managed and native code. So from the operating system's POV it is just a 32-bit dll and cannot be loaded into a 64-bit process. If Oracle provides both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of this assembly, you will have to modify your deployment procedures to ensure that the correct assembly is installed. If only a 32-bit assembly is available, you can do little except make your managed application x86 rather than anycpu. If this is impractical, one solution is to create a separate 32-bit service process which will load this assembly, and have the main 64-bit process communicate with it using an IPC mechanism selected to taste.

Comment: the type passed to XmlSerializer is not having any of its properties from the Oracle dll, still why is it trying to load it ?

Comment: Maybe its code refers to this assembly (possibly indirectly, through another assembly). Base classes, attributes, extension methods... Try setting a breakpoint in the assembly resolve event and take a look at the stack trace/locals.